# Toshiba Satelite T135 temperature is always above normal

Tags: laptop, fan, temperature

I just did the great jump from Windows to Ubuntu on my Toshiba Satelite T135. It works wonderful tough I have a couple of problems. I can't change my screen brightness at all and the fan sensors don't work as they have to.
 
 When I used windows the fans were working very silently almost all the time except when the temperature was above 56°c so the laptop fan worked until the ideal temperature was reached, which was 50°c.

Now In Ubuntu they work silently even if its above 59°c and only work at high speeds when it is very hot and what is worse is that when it gets even hotter, the fan seem to interpret that it is in the ideal temp so they wont work at all!

I have installed the following software:

·libsensors4
·lm-sensors
·fancontrol
·toshset
·toshutils

But with none of this I can did anything except from some sensor testing. Something interesting is that toshset and toshutils don't run at all, toshet gives this when I run it: "required kernel toshiba support not enabled." and toshutils: "laptop does not have cooling fan or kernel module not installed".

Sorry If the solution is too obvious but I am stuck here, maybe is stupid but I think this Baclkight and Fan problem is something related with the ACPI, because with Ubuntu 10.10 i had to add "acpi=off" to the "silent splash" thing before booting or it wouldn't boot and stop in something that sayed kernel_thread_helper or something I don't remember. (Now I am in Ubuntu 11.04) 
 I really appreciate if someone could help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

use

sudo setpci -s 00:02.0 F4.B=#

where # = 0 to 99 to set the brightness of the screen. So far, the nomodeset acpi_backlight=vendor will crash xorg under 11.04

For more information, join this launchpad team and have a look at the mailing list:

http://launchpad.net/~toshiba-t100-series

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help you, but give it a try.
I was experiencing the overheating and realized that my processor was running full speed all the time (which makes the laptop hotter and the battery shorter).
Log in to the classic desktop and add the frequency applet (it's called something like that) to the panel  and check if it's running at full speed all the time.
What I had to do was load the appropriate kernel modules (don't know why Ubuntu wasn't automatically loading them), which were (in my case, yours might be different) powernow-k8
and cpufreq_ondemand and added them to my /etc/modules.

Here is some great info, but note that it's not meant specifically for Ubuntu, so some things might be done differently (specially the /etc/rc.conf, which does not exist in Ubuntu, you have to add the modules to /etc/modules instead) 
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Cpufreq

Hope this helps!